# iPhone Coverflow

Tags: iphone

I need to implement cover flow functionality to our iPhone application. I tried to find sample code online to get started with it, but I didn't have any luck. Can anyone tell me how to implement cover flow functionality or give me a sample?

Thanks In Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try FlowCover at

http://www.chaosinmotion.com/flowcover.m

the source code provides you with a FlowCoverView realizing the coverflow effect.
You simply need to customize a few delegate methods. Take a look at the example source code, customizing it to suit your needs should be straightforward.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you plz explain me what BSD license is?

Comment: Basically the BSD license allows you to use the code for both non commercial and commercial applications. You only need to add to your application the few lines of text (shown in the license itself) stating that the original source code of FlowCover belongs to his author.

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to check out a library I released at iPhoneDevCamp -- OpenFlow. http://apparentlogic.com/openflow

It is all core animation-based, so it's easy to understand and customize to your needs. AFOpenFlowView is a subclass of UIView.

I included a demo application, and check out the blog entry on my personal website for a bit more information about its use. fajkowski.com

Drop me a line if you have any questions or comments! 
-Alex

Comment: how do i resize bigger images in coverflow??Could you please guide me in that direction?? or i have to put all images of same size??

Answer (score 0):

This one looks promising:

https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

Seems to be more actively maintained than the other two suggested above.