# Imagegallery with animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, image-gallery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone Coverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767048/iphone-coverflow)

I need to create a photogallery like https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/retailmenot-coupons/id521207075?ls=1&mt=8 this one . is anybody know the name of this animation effect, or  sample code for the same. i cant search with out a name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This animation is called coverflow animation you want to use the more coverflow effect using the API then check out this link https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

Answer (score 1):

This type of image representing gallery called a Coverflow and this is a demo of this type of animation photo gallery please downlode demo from this link http://www.chaosinmotion.com/flowcover.html hope its helps you

Answer (score 1):

Yes the type of the animation used in the application is the **Coverflow** animation and this animation has two types. Both of those and many more can be found at [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel).

This is one open source control for iOS.

The author says

> iCarousel is a class designed to simplify the implementation of
>   various types of carousel (paged, scrolling views) on iPhone, iPad and
>   Mac OS. iCarousel implements a number of common effects such as
>   cylindrical, flat and "CoverFlow" style carousels, as well as
>   providing hooks to implement your own bespoke effects. Unlike many
>   other "CoverFlow" libraries, iCarousel can work with any kind of view,
>   not just images, so it is ideal for presenting paged data in a fluid
>   and impressive way in your app. It also makes it extremely easy to
>   swap between different carousel effects with minimal code changes.
>
> **Supported OS & SDK Versions**
>
> Supported build target - iOS 5.1 / Mac OS 10.7 (Xcode 4.4.1, Apple LLVM compiler 4.0)
>  
>   Earliest supported deployment target - iOS 4.3 / Mac OS 10.7 
>   Earliest compatible deployment target - iOS 3.2 / Mac OS 10.6

And much many more supports and it is improved constantly over time.

Coverflow/Coverflow2:

[image: CF2]
[image: CF]

Other supported animations:

[image: List]

Answer (score 1):

There is a open source library called Tapku for doing the coverflow effect.

Here is the [github link](https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary) for downloading the project.

Here is a nice [tutorial](http://www.applausible.com/blog/?p=657) for implementing the coverflow.

The screen will look like this:

[image: CoverFlow]